# Error de sintaxis en netbeans/mariaDB consulta

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mariadb

Estoy tratando de crear una variable en netbeans de consulta para insertar valores (con campos aun no declarados, dependiendo que se ingrese por teclado) mi gestor de base de datos es mariaDB, la conexion está correcta pero al intentar guardar un nuevo paciente me lanza este error :

> No se pudo guardar You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '12234-8, Juan, M, 0, Av.ArturoPrat, Pichilemu, S,
>   true)' at line 1[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5cbc508c

la sintaxis declarada la tengo escrita de esta forma:

```
 public int Guardar (Paciente nuevo) throws Exception
    {
        int res =1;
        String sql = "insert into paciente (rut, nombre, genero, edad, direccion, ciudad, isapre, donante)VALUES  "
                + "(" + "," + nuevo.getRut() + ", " + nuevo.getNombre()  + ", " +nuevo.getGenero()  + ", "+ nuevo.getEdad()   + ", "
                + nuevo.getDireccion()+", "+ nuevo.getCiudad()  + ", "+ nuevo.getIsapre()  + ", " + nuevo.isDonante()+")";

        try
        {
            st=con.createStatement();
            res = st.executeUpdate(sql);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              throw new Exception ("No se pudo guardar" + " "+ ex.getLocalizedMessage()+ ""+ ex.getStackTrace())  ;      
        }

        return res;
    }
```

y mi nuevo paciente así:

```
Paciente nuevo=new Paciente("12234-8","Juan", 'M', 78, "Av.ArturoPrat","Pichilemu", 'S', true);
```

Donde esta su rut, nombre, Masculino (M es un char), su edad, su direccion, ciudad, S (Si es de isapre un char), y true si es de isapre (boolean).

Gracias.

Comment: Si pones un System.out.println(sql);  justo antes del try ¿te salen comillas en las cadenas que mandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El query para insertar los datos es incorrecto, recuerda que los campos que contienen datos de tipo `CHAR` y `VARCHAR` deben usar comillas como contenedores.

Realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
String sql = "insert into paciente (rut, nombre, genero, edad, direccion, ciudad, isapre, donante)VALUES  "
                + "('" + "," + nuevo.getRut() + "', '" + nuevo.getNombre()  + "', '" +nuevo.getGenero()  + "', "+ nuevo.getEdad()   + ", '"
                + nuevo.getDireccion()+"', '"+ nuevo.getCiudad()  + "', '"+ nuevo.getIsapre()  + "', " + nuevo.isDonante()+")";
```

Comment: Muuuchas gracias !!! me salvaste la vida :( <3

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un campo vació antes de enviar rut:

```
+ "(" + ",
```

En el query eso queda así: `(,ValorRut`

Pon lo así: `+ "('"+ nuevo.getRut()+"'"` ademas te falta el apostrofe antes y al final de cada campo.

Comment: El apóstrofe para los campos VARCHAR, no?

Comment: Si, pero como es `mysql/mariaDB` deberías ponérselos incluso a los que no son cadena, tal como si ejecutaras el query en el workbench mysl. Aunque es mejor que uses sentencias preparadas para que tu código no sea susceptible a inyección sql.

Comment: Para los nombres de campo, sí. Para los valores, no. Los valores deben ir entre comillas

Comment: Muuuchas gracias !!! se pasaron :) !